# Set the user session expiry

Tags: swift, server-side, vapor

I need to set the expiry time for the user session in Vapor 2 (or for cookies in general), but can't see how to do it. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Are you using the `SessionsMiddleware` built in to Vapor or are you creating your own cookies?

Comment: I'm using the SessionMiddleware

Answer (score 2):

Cookies can be set with a [`max-age`](https://github.com/vapor/engine/blob/master/Sources/Cookies/Cookie.swift#L12) after which they expire. This is the best way to set a time limit on your user's sessions.

Unfortunately Vapor's `SessionsMiddleware` doesn't include baked-in support for putting an age limit on the session cookie, but it's not too hard to create the SessionsMiddleware manually and override the [`cookieFactory`](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/blob/master/Sources/Sessions/SessionsMiddleware.swift#L29-L35) closure.

```
let sessionsMiddleware = try SessionsMiddleware(config.resolveSessions(), cookieName: "my-sessions-cookie-name", cookieFactory: { request in
  return Cookie(
    name: "my-sessions-cookie-name",
    value: "",
    maxAge: 3600,
    httpOnly: true
  )
})
```

Comment: did you need to add any special `import` statements for this?

Comment: @rustyMagnet `import Sessions` ought to do it. Bear in mind also this answer is for Vapor 2, which is no longer the most current.

Comment: I also needed `Cookies` as an import.  Interestingly, my middleware validates for the presence of a cookie but not of an expired or replayed cookie.